# ¿Como conectar SQLite a Electron con react vite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, electron, vite

estoy intentando configurar el ipcRenderer el ipcMain del electron para poder conectar al sqlite y lo hice esta manera, al principio conecta pero después no llegan los datos a mi react. la base ya esta cargada y tiene las comulumnas asignadas perfectamente

ipcMain esto esta dentro del main.js:

```
    const dbPath = join(app.getPath('userData'), 'db_sqlite.db')
  const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Hubo un problema con la base de datos SQLite, error:', err.message)
    } else {
      console.log('Conectado a la base de datos SQLite')
      db.run(esto es la creacion de la tabla)
    }
  })

  // Manejar consultas a la base de datos
  ipcMain.on('consulta-db', (event, consultaSQL) => {
    if (!db) {
      event.reply('resultado-db', { error: 'La base de datos no está disponible' });
      return;
    }

    db.all(consultaSQL, [], (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        event.reply('resultado-db', { error: err.message });
      } else {
        event.reply('resultado-db', { rows });
      }
    });
  });
```

ipcRenderer que esta en preload.js

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import { electronAPI } from '@electron-toolkit/preload';

const api = {};

if (process.contextIsolated) {
  try {
    const extendedElectronAPI = {
      ...electronAPI,
      ipcRenderer: {
        send: (channel, data) => {
          ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        },
        on: (channel, listener) => {
          ipcRenderer.on(channel, (_, ...args) => listener(...args));
        },
        removeAllListeners: (channel) => {
          ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(channel);
        },
      },
    };

    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', extendedElectronAPI);
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', api);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
} else {
  window.electron = electronAPI;
  window.api = api;
}
```

estoy usando electron con vite y pude crear la app desde https://electron-vite.org/guide/
instale sqlite3 y el error que me sale cuando quiero conectar es que desde el preload no llegan los datos de la base. si alguien mas experimentado entiende lo necesito